# Unity register generic type for non generic interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, unity-container

my scenario looks (to me) very straight forward, but I couldn't find a resolution.

I have this scenario

```
public class Class<T> : IInterface where T : class
{ 

}
```

the interface cannot be made generic (coming from WCF lib.)

so I want to register the interface like this

```
container.RegisterType(typeof (IInterface ), typeof (Class<>));
```

and then resolve it with T

How can I do it? What am I missing?

my intention is doing something like

```
container.Resolve<IInterface>(/* specify T */);
```

Comment: You have to specify a type in the Class<> in order for typeof to work properly, presumably you wanted to cast IInterface to a specific type of Class<T>, e.g. Class<Order> ?

Comment: no i didn't- i wanted to implement this interface in a generic way and i need the T to be dynamic.

Comment: @Tom: How would you implement this if you weren't using Unity? Please update your question with some code that shows this. This hopefully allows us to better understand what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: if i wasn't using unity i would use the factory you suggested. but i think that unity can handle this, since i want to tell him what is T when i am resolving the instance.

Comment: @Tom: You can't tell Unity this, and you shouldn't tell Unity this. This is where the factory pattern is designed for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't *need* to resolve using the uncontrolled interface, you can make your own controlled interface which uses generics and derives from the uncontrolled interface.  Then you can register the open generic and resolve the closed generic types.

```
public interface IControlled<T> : IUncontrolled {}
public class Controlled<T> : IControlled<T> {}

container.RegisterType(typeof(IControlled<>), typeof(Controlled<>));

IUncontrolled instance = container.Resolve<IControlled<string>>();
```

Comment: great - simple and elegant

Answer (score 8):

> What am I missing?

You are missing a factory.

Think about it, there are no magic leprechauns working on the background guessing the type you need. You need to supply it. Either by explicitly stating what `T` is while configuring like this:

```
container.RegisterType(
    typeof(IInterface),
    typeof(Class<SomeType>));
```

Or by creating a factory where you pass on the `T` at runtime:

```
public interface IInterfaceFactory
{
    IInterface Create<T>();
}
```

The factory can be registered as follows:

```
container.RegisterInstance<IInterfaceFactory>(
    new InterfaceFactory(container));
```

And an implementation can look as follows:

```
public class InterfaceFactory : IInterfaceFactory
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;
    public InterfaceFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public IInterface Create<T>()
    {
        return this.container.Resolve<Class<T>>();
    }
}
```

Now you can inject the `IInterfaceFactory` into consumers that need to work with `IInterface` and they can request the version they need by calling the `Create<T>()` method.

**UPDATE**

If you think this is too much code, you can also register a factory delegate as follows:

```
container.RegisterInstance<Func<Type, IInterface>>(
    type => container.Resolve(
        typeof(Class<>).MakeGenericType(type)));
```

This is basically the same, but now inlined in a delegate. Your consumers can now depend on a `Func<Type, IInterface>` instead of a `IInterfaceFactory` and pass a type instance on to the delegate.

I personally prefer the use of a descriptive interface such as `IInterfaceFactory`. It's up to you.

Comment: your solution looks like too complicated for me. i want unity to do this for me - i will resolve with the actual T so unity can inject it to the class that is registered on the interface.

Comment: Very elegant solution imo!

Comment: Excellent solution!