# Unity can't resolve Generic repository

Tags: c#, unity-container, repository-pattern

I saw other questions similar to this, but it did not solve my problem. Example of one question: [Unity register generic type for non generic interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482247/unity-register-generic-type-for-non-generic-interface)

I have the interface

```
    public interface IRepository<T>
    {
        T GetById(int id);
    }
```

and the class

```
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
    {
         public T GetById(int id)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Type: " + GetType());
             return default(T);
         }
    }
```

I register it

```
    Container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
```

and try to resolve it

```
    IRepository<string> IRepository = Container.Resolve<IRepository<string>>();
```

It always returns null.

I saw many different sources and they all show the same way of implementing it. Why does it not work?

**UPDATE**

This is the actual implementation:

```
public class Program
{
    static Program()
    {
        DIDefaultRegisters.Initialize();
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var iRepository = UnityDIFacade.Resolve<IRepository<string>>();

        iRepository.GetById(1);
    }
}

public class DIDefaultRegisters
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Register(typeof(IRepository<>),typeof(Repository<>));
    }

    private static void Register(Type from, Type to)
    {
        UnityDIFacade.RegisterType(from, to);
    }
}

public class UnityDIFacade
{
    private static readonly IUnityContainer Container;

    static UnityDIFacade()
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        var section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
        if (section != null)
            section.Configure(container);

        Container = container;
    }

    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        T resolved = default(T);

        if (Container.IsRegistered<T>()) 
            resolved = Container.Resolve<T>();

        return resolved;
    }

    public static void RegisterType(Type from, Type to)
    {
        Container.RegisterType(from, to);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the check `if (Container.IsRegistered<T>())` in your code, cause this will return `false` for each repository you request. The concret repositories like `IRepository<string>`, `IRepository<User>`  etc. are not registered in the container only the generic version of `IRepository<T>`.

If you want to return `null`, then use a try-catch-block around `Container.Resolve` to set resolved to null in case of an exception.

```
public static T Resolve<T>()
{
    T resolved;

    //if (Container.IsRegistered<T>()) 
    try{
      resolved = Container.Resolve<T>();
    }
    catch(Exception){
      resolved = default(T);
    }
    return resolved;
}
```

Comment: With your update I understand. So it actually registers the generic "version". I changed the code and added the try-catch block and it now works. I ask you to remove "= default(T)" at the beginning, because We should assign default(T) to resolved in the catch. Then I'll set your answer as solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I made this small test with Unity to try to understand your problem (I had to change the `GetById` method a bit). However, it works just as expected, prints `Type: System.DateTime`

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T GetById(int id);
}
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type: " + typeof(T));
        return default(T);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));

        IRepository<DateTime> iRepository = container.Resolve<IRepository<DateTime>>();

        iRepository.GetById(4);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use the code exatly as yours, it works as well. I added my implementation (it's simple). Please, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I liked **Jehof & ThB0Y** answer. But I did not like catching an exception. I have written my own IsRegisteredInternal method to check for unresolved Generics as well.

```
public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        T ret = default(T);

        if (IsRegisteredInternal<T>())
        {
            ret = Container.Resolve<T>();
        }

        return ret;
    }

    private static bool IsRegisteredInternal<T>()
    {
        if (Container.IsRegistered<T>())
            return true;
        if (typeof(T).IsGenericType)
        {
            return Container.IsRegistered(typeof(T).GetGenericTypeDefinition());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

*Note : IsRegistered() enumerates through Container.Registrations*