# Unity - Resolve dependency based on generic type

Tags: c#, generics, inversion-of-control, unity-container, azure-cosmosdb

I have a class named `DocumentRepository<T>`
with constructor

```
DocumentDbRepository(IDocumentCollectionName collectionName)
```

Where **IDocumentCollectionName** can be

```
CollectionNameFromClassName<T>
```

or

```
CollectionNameFromString
```

And I am resolving this by

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IDocumentDbRepository<ClassA>), typeof(DocumentDbRepository<ClassA>))

container.RegisterType(typeof(IDocumentDbRepository<ClassB>), typeof(DocumentDbRepository<ClassB>))
```

So far so good.

But now I want to resolve **IDocumentCollectionName** to either `CollectionNameFromClassName` or `CollectionNameFromString` depending on the Generic Type.

So if I have `ClassA`, I want **IDocumentCollectionName** to resolve to `CollectionNameFromClassName<ClassA>`

And if i have ClassB, I want **IDocumentCollectionName** to resolve to `CollectionNameFromString` with a string parameter value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity Register For One Interface Multiple Object and Tell Unity Where to Inject them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665324/unity-register-for-one-interface-multiple-object-and-tell-unity-where-to-inject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here 
[Unity register generic type for non generic interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482247/unity-register-generic-type-for-non-generic-interface)

end code looks like

```
container.RegisterInstance<Func<Type, IDocumentCollectionName>>(type =>
{
    if (type == typeof(ClassA))
        return
            (IDocumentCollectionName)
                container.Resolve(typeof(CollectionNameFromClassName<>).MakeGenericType(type));
    else
        return (IDocumentCollectionName)
            container.Resolve(typeof(CollectionNameFromString));

});
```

of course this means that I had to change my

```
DocumentDbRepository(IDocumentCollectionName collectionName)
```

to

```
Func<Type, IDocumentCollectionName> collectionName
```

and resolve it as

```
collectionName(typeof(T))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665324/unity-register-for-one-interface-multiple-object-and-tell-unity-where-to-inject), this might work:

```
container.RegisterType<IDocumentCollectionName, CollectionNameFromClassName<ClassA>>("ForClassA");
container.RegisterType<IDocumentCollectionName, CollectionNameFromString>("ForClassB");

container.RegisterType<IDocumentDbRepository<ClassA>, DocumentDbRepository<ClassA>>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IDocumentCollectionName>("ForClassA")));
container.RegisterType<IDocumentDbRepository<ClassB>, DocumentDbRepository<ClassB>>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IDocumentCollectionName>("ForClassB")));
```

**EDIT:** If lisibility is your concern, I can propose to you, this:

First, you create a function to do something like your factory:

```
void RegisterDocumentDbRepository<TRepository, TCollection>(ContainerType container)
{
    container.RegisterType<IDocumentCollectionName, TCollection>(typeof(TRepository).Name);
    var constructor = new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IDocumentCollectionName>(typeof(TRepository).Name));
    container.RegisterType<IDocumentDbRepository<TRepository>, DocumentDbRepository<TRepository>>(constructor);
}
```

Then, you register your type like this:

```
RegisterDocumentDbRepository<ClassA, CollectionNameFromClassName<ClassA>>(container);
RegisterDocumentDbRepository<ClassB, CollectionNameFromString>(container);
```

Comment: This does work. I tried it, but I didn't like it very much. But I think using the factory method works better. Its bit easier to read.http://stackoverflow.com/a/18482602/6731559

Comment: And what about with this edit, does it better for you ?